# Make WooCommerce products featured programmatically

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, hook-woocommerce

I've tried:

```
update_post_meta( $product->ID, '_featured', 'true');
```

But it didn't seem to work

I'm seeing that that removed this as the way to update the featured status of products in WooCommerce but can't find how to do it now

Im trying to get all of my featured and non featured dokan sellers and then update all of their products as featured or non featured based on their store featured status, through something like this:

```
   $args = array( 'featured' => 'yes' );
   $featured = dokan_get_sellers( $args );
   
   $args = array( 'featured' => 'no' );
   $not_featured = dokan_get_sellers( $args );
   
    foreach ( $featured['users'] as $seller ) {
    $products_f = get_posts( array(
      'post_type' => 'product',
      'author' => $featured->ID,
      'posts_per_page' => -1
    ) );
    }
   foreach ( $not_featured['users'] as $seller ) {
    $products_nf = get_posts( array(
      'post_type' => 'product',
      'author' => $not_featured->ID,
      'posts_per_page' => -1
    ) );
    }
  foreach ( $products_f as $product) {

      update_post_meta( $product->ID, '_featured', 'true');
    }
 foreach ( $products_nf as $product) {

      update_post_meta( $product->ID, '_featured', 'false');
    }
```

Current code:

```
add_action( 'set_featured_hook', 'set_featured' );
function set_featured(){
   $args_featured = array( 'featured' => 'yes' );
   $featured = dokan_get_sellers( $args_featured );
   
   $args_nf = array( 'featured' => 'no' );
   $not_featured = dokan_get_sellers( $args_nf );
   
    foreach ( $featured['users'] as $seller ) {
    $products_f = get_posts( array(
      'post_type' => 'product',
      'author' => $seller->ID,
      'posts_per_page' => -1
    ) );
    }
    
    foreach ( $not_featured['users'] as $seller ) {
    $products_nf = get_posts( array(
      'post_type' => 'product',
      'author' => $seller->ID,
      'posts_per_page' => -1
    ) );
    }
 foreach ($products_f as $product) {
    $wc_product_f = wc_get_product($product->ID);
    $wc_product_f ->set_featured(1);
    $wc_product_f ->save();
}

 foreach ($products_nf as $product) {
    $wc_product_nf = wc_get_product($product->ID);
    $wc_product_nf->set_featured(0);
    $wc_product_nf->save();
}
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
foreach ($products_f as $product) {
    $wc_product = wc_get_product($product->ID);
    $wc_product->set_featured(1);
    $wc_product->save();
}
foreach ($products_nf as $product) {
    $wc_product = wc_get_product($product->ID);
    $wc_product->set_featured(0);
    $wc_product->save();
}
```

Use the built-in WooCommerce method `set_featured()` for updating the product.

Comment: thank you for catching this, i've made these changes and those described by you and faisal and ran a wp-cron for the function, and it seemed to work. However, the products of only one vendor were set as featured even though i have two featured vendors for some reason? I have updated the code with what i am currently using